# Making a validation function to tell if the number entered is positve

Tags: c

/* this is just a function I'm trying to make for a bigger program that calcs the area of a room. When the answer <= 0 I want to get the function to take over, but I keep getting to few arguments error when I compile it. Any help will be gladly appreciated.*/

```
#include <stdio.h>
int validInput(double len);
int main(void)
{
double len ;
int check;
printf("\nEnter length of room in feet:");
        scanf("%lf", &len);
check = validInput();

return 0;

}

int validInput(double len)
{
int check;
if (len <= 0 )
printf("\nNumbers entered must be positive.");
return check;
}
```

Comment: I'm a college student trying to learn more code.

Comment: You've written that `validInput` takes one argument. But then when you try to call it, you're not giving it an argument?

Comment: To @immibis 's point, in your main function you are calling your validInput function. Below, you define that function as needing some kind of argument.
Also, regarding your validInput function, I wonder what is being returned.
`check`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line:

```
check = validInput();
```

is missing the parameter.  Suggest:

```
check = validInput( len );
```

Of course, the code should check the returned value, not the parameter value, from the call to `scanf()` to assure the operation was successful.  In this case, the returned value should be 1.  any other returned value would indicate an error occurred.

regarding the `validInput()` function:

the variable `check` is never initialized to any specific value.  Suggest:

```
int validInput(double len)
{
    int check = 1; // indicate valid

    if (len <= 0 )
    {
        check = 0; // indicate not valid
        printf("\nNumbers entered must be positive.\n");
    }

    return check;
}
```

Note: the trailing `\n` on the call to `printf()` is to force the text to be output immediately rather than setting in the internal `stdout` buffer until the program exits, at which time it would be output.

incorporating appropriate error checking into the `main()` function results in:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // scanf(), printf()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

int validInput(double len);

int main(void)
{
    double len ;
    int check;

    printf("\nEnter length of room in feet:");
    if( 1 != scanf("%lf", &len) )
    { // then scanf failed
        perror( "scanf for length of room, in feet, failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    check = validInput( len );

    printf( "the user input was %s\n", (check)? "valid" : "not valid");

    return 0;

} // end function: main
```

Answer (score 1):

First... you didn't pass any value to validInput(). I guess your code here above won't even compile...

You should change this line:

```
check = validInput();
```

to:

```
check = validInput(len);
```

Also consider that variable "check" returned by your function is neither initialised nor set...

P.S. please indent your code...

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed it. I will fix the format on my post++.